# jenkins dynamically build jobs with different parameters in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline that calls a certain REST API and every time gets a job description to run with the following structure:

```
{
    "jobName": "job_name",
    "parameters": []
}
```

e.g.

```
{
    "jobName": "tzach_job1",
    "parameters":
    [
        {
            "param1": "value1"
        },
        {
            "param2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            
            steps {
                script {
def job1 = readJSON text: '''{
    "jobName": "tzach_job1",
    "parameters":
    [
        {
            "param1": "value1"
        },
        {
            "param2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}'''

def job2 = readJSON text: '''{
    "jobName": "tzach_job2",
    "parameters":
    [
        {
            "param_a": "tzach"
        },
        {
            "param_b": "yariv"
        },
        {
            "param_c": "just another value"
        }
    ]
}'''

                run_job(job1)
                run_job(job2)
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def run_job(jobJson){
    def parametersList = []
   
   jobJson.parameters.each { 
       // there is only 1 key and one value
       keys = it.keySet()
       values = it.values()
       parametersList.add([$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: "${keys[0]}", value: "${values[0]}"])
   }
   
   build job: jobJson.jobName, parameters: parametersList
}
```